# Visual studio sql compare does not update newly added table

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I added a new table in the sql server db and used visual studio sql compare to compare it to the existing db project. When i select the newly added table in the comparison results and say update, it does not show up in tfs pending changes.

Updates to procs show up in pending changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Before or after saving all of the changes to the project? Did you verify that the table file itself was updated and saved?

Comment: By updating target i would assume it would add the newly added table to pending changes. AM i wrong?

Comment: In my experience if you haven't actually saved the file(s) after they're updated I don't think there's anything to pick up - thus me asking if they had been saved (Ctrl+Shift+S will usually save all pending changes). I know I've missed things in Git because I had added a new object, but not saved the actual sqlproj file to include those new objects. That led to a new commit/checkin so I'd catch it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the compare again and it should go green.
it'll confirm that it was committed. Then check the project to see if the file is listed and has an addition graphic + in tfs

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience i did rebuild the solution and compared again then it showing correct